# Any way to replace a DNS Server address in my /etc/resolv.conf using python in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: python, dns, ubuntu-12.04

What is the best approach for developing a program in python that can replace an old DNS Server address for a new one in Ubuntu 12.04?

UPDATE:
Basically what I need is a way to update my resolv.conf file content so that I can replace the nameservers configured in there.

So for example I have in my resolv.conf:

```
 nameserver 10.0.0.1
 nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

And I need to somehow modify to have the values:

```
 nameserver 10.0.0.3
 nameserver 10.0.0.4
```

I need to make this using python(or any scripting language or even by command line), because I need to do this in a user-friendly window that must run in a kiosk-mode Xubuntu.

**NOTE:

So far I have tried finding an ubuntu command that can achieve this, but I haven't found one.

I have also tried modifying /etc/resolv.conf but Python has no ability to modify a file, so I need to delete the file and create the file with the new content, however I have no permission to do this (already tried chmod 777 and chattr -a but they didn't work)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  You mention `resolv.conf`, which is for configuring your resolver, but doesn't typically have anything to do with "dns entries".  There are a variety of DNS servers out there, several of which support dynamic updates.  What is your server?  Python can of course modify files; there are lots of examples out there demonstrating basic file i/o.  If your server supports DNS updates via DDNS, you can use the `nsupdate` command.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant, I want to modify my resolver @larsks . I will update my question so that it is clearer thank you. Can you tell me any way to modify a file without having to delete the original and replacing it with one with the same name please? I am not using a server, It is just a laptop in kiosk mode running an app, and I want this app to modify that file.

Comment: I'm not clear on something: do you actually have permission to modify this file?  Because if you don't, you're pretty much stuck.  Typically, only the `root` user can modify this file.  Also, if you could update your question to show exactly what you want do do (e.g., initial state and desired end state) we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: I do not have permission.. well I gave my file a chmod 777, I CAN modify it but not using python so far cause every example I've found for modifying files involves deleting and making that file over again. Ok I'll try to be a little more specific in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of editing task `sed` is often your best friend.  To accomplish your example, the following would work:

```
sed -i '
  s/10\.0\.0\.1/10.0.0.3/
  s/10\.0\.0\.2/10.0.0.4/
' /etc/resolv.conf
```

This uses the search-and-replace operator, `s//`.  The `-i` flag causes `sed` to modify the file in place, rather than printing the modified version on stdout.

Note that I am escaping the periods (`.`) in the match expression because in regular expressions, which `sed` uses for it's match syntax, the `.` character is a wildcard.

However, if you're simply switching between two different configurations, just replacing the file is probably the simplest solution:

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf.config1 /etc/resolv.conf
```